# Not able to run Pyinstaller executable on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pyinstaller

I am trying out `pyinstaller` for the first time. I created a file named `hello.py` with just one line of code:

```
print "hello"
```

I used the following command to make a binary:

```
pyinstaller hello.py
```

The process completed successfully and a binary was created at `dist/hello`. I am not able to run this binary file. When I tried to run it from the terminal, I got,

```
bash: .: hello: cannot execute binary file
```

I tried to double click it from `nautilus` but nothing is happening. 
How can I run this binary file?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What's the output of the command `file /path/to/yourexecutable/hello`?

Comment: Also, you need the whole `dist/hello` folder, not just the executable.

Comment: @Locoluis, I am running the file from the dist folder itself. The output is `hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=373ec5dee826653796e927ac3d65c9a8ec7db9da, stripped`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it running by typing the relative path `dist/hello` in terminal

Comment: tq u bro... I was facing same problem... tq so much

Answer (score 3):

for linux (tested on ubuntu 16.04 python3)
    `pyinstaller hello.py --onefile` it create one file named `hello`.
Then go inside dist folder use terminal
    `cd dist`.
Then
    `./hello`.
Looks not as windows way , but work. `./hello` is something like ,  run outside...